# MVC3 Custom HTMLHelper, partial view or other solution to apply DRY principle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got an MVC3 Read Only view that contains a table displaying properties for an Item.

For many of the properties of the Item, we track the changes a Vendor has made to the item.  So, for example, a vendor may update a property named 'Color' from a value of 'Blue' to 'Red'.  In this View a table lists each property tracked in a table row, with a column showing the 'Old Value' and the 'New Value'.  The next column either shows the current change's status (Awaiting Approval, Approved, or Rejected).  However, for Admin users, the column will contain Links ('Approve', 'Reject', or 'Reset to Awaiting Approval').

My markup and Razor code for this is very repetitive and getting out of hand.  I'd like to create an HTMLHelper for this, or possibly a partial view that I can use to move all the code into and then use it for each Item Property.

Here is an example of the code used for one Property. This code is repeated for another 10 or so properties.

I'm using some jquery and ajax for the actions.  For example, when an change is rejected, the user must enter a reason for rejecting the change.

```
    <tr id="rowId-color">
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Color)</td>
        @if (Model.ChangeLog != null && Model.ChangeLog.Item("Color") != null) {
            var change = Model.ChangeLog.Item("Color");
            var changeStatus = (ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses)change.ItemChangeStatusID;
            <td>@change.OldValueDisplay</td>
            <td id="tdstatusId-@change.ItemChangeID">                                                                                
                @if (changeStatus == ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.AwaitingApproval && User.IsInRole("TVAPMgr")) {
                                            @Ajax.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Approve this change?", OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" })
                                            @Html.Raw("|")
                                            <a href="#dialog" name="reject" data-id="@change.ItemChangeID" >Reject</a>
                }
                else if ((changeStatus == ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.Rejected || changeStatus == ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.Approved) && User.IsInRole("TVAPMgr")) { 
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Reset to Awaiting Approval", "Reset", new { itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Reset this change to Awaiting Approval?", OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" })
                }
                else {
                    @changeStatus.ToDisplayString()
                }
            </td> 
            <td  id="tdreasonId-@change.ItemChangeID">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChangeLog.Item(change.ItemChangeID).RejectedReason)</td>
        }
        else {
            <td colspan="3">No Change</td>
        }
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown nor explained how your domain and view models look like but I suspect that what you are using here is not an appropriate view model for this specific requirement of the view. A better view model would have been one that has a list of properties to approve which would be shown in the table.

Anyway, one possible approach is to write a custom HTML helper so that your view looks like this:

```
<tr id="rowId-color">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Color)
    @Html.ChangeLogFor(x => x.Color)
</tr>
...
```

and the helper might be something along the line of:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ChangeLogFor<TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<MyViewModel, TProperty>> ex
    )
    {
        var model = html.ViewData.Model;
        var itemName = ((MemberExpression)ex.Body).Member.Name;
        var change = model.ChangeLog.Item(itemName);
        if (change == null)
        {
            return new HtmlString("<td colspan=\"3\">No Change</td>");
        }

        var isUserTVAPMgr = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("TVAPMgr");
        var changeStatus = (ItemChangeStatuses)change.ItemChangeStatusID;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", html.Encode(change.OldValueDisplay));
        sb.AppendFormat("<td id=\"tdstatusId-{0}\">", change.ItemChangeID);
        var ajax = new AjaxHelper<MyViewModel>(html.ViewContext, html.ViewDataContainer);
        if (changeStatus == ItemChangeStatuses.AwaitingApproval && isUserTVAPMgr)
        {
            sb.Append(
                ajax.ActionLink(
                    "Approve", 
                    "Approve", 
                    new { 
                        itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID 
                    }, 
                    new AjaxOptions { 
                        HttpMethod = "POST", 
                        Confirm = "Approve this change?", 
                        OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" 
                }).ToHtmlString()
            );
            sb.Append("|");
            sb.AppendFormat("<a href=\"#dialog\" name=\"reject\" data-id=\"{0}\">Reject</a>", change.ItemChangeID);
        }
        else if ((changeStatus == ItemChangeStatuses.Rejected || changeStatus == ItemChangeStatuses.Approved) && isUserTVAPMgr)
        {
            sb.Append(
                ajax.ActionLink(
                    "Reset to Awaiting Approval", 
                    "Reset", 
                    new { 
                        itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID 
                    }, 
                    new AjaxOptions { 
                        HttpMethod = "POST", 
                        Confirm = "Reset this change to Awaiting Approval?", 
                        OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" 
                    }
                ).ToHtmlString()
            );
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(changeStatus.ToDisplayString());
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</td>");
        sb.AppendFormat(
            "<td id=\"tdreasonId-{0}\">{1}</td>", 
            change.ItemChangeID, 
            html.Encode(model.ChangeLog.Item(change.ItemChangeID).RejectedReason)
        );
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

A better approach would be to re-adapt your view model to the requirements of this view and simply use display templates.

Comment: I've used your code almost verbatim, and it's working for most properties. However, the Change tracking is using property names as keys, however they don't always match with this Model's properties.  For example, the Model has a property Material, but the change uses a key of MaterialID.  Is there a data annotation I can use to associate the two?  I was thinking of use the KeyAttribute in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Comment: @JeffReddy, yeah you could use data annotations for this case. Their values will be read from the model metadata inside the helper.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had hoped. Been googleing this for a bit now.  Trying to figure out what data annotation to use and how to get values from metadata as well as how to access the metadata at all from my helper.

Answer (score 2):

This really sounds more like a DisplayTemplate for the `ItemChangeModel` type, that way you can just do:

```
 <tr id="rowId-color">
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Color)</td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChangeLog.Item("Color"))
</tr>
```

For each ChangeLog cell and the display template then is like a mini-view with a typed model of `ItemChangeModel`.  So your view file would like like this:

```
@model ItemChangeModel

@if(Model != null) {

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OldValueDisplay)</td>
<td id="tdstatusId-@Model.ItemChangeID">

@switch((ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses) Model.ItemChangeStatusID) {

    case ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.AwaitingApproval:
        if(User.IsInRole("TVAPMgr")) {

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", new { itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Approve this change?", OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" })

            @Html.Raw("|")

            <a href="#dialog" name="reject" data-id="@change.ItemChangeID" >Reject</a>

        }
        break;

    case ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.Rejected:
    case ItemEnumerations.ItemChangeStatuses.Approved:

        if(User.IsInRole("TVAPMgr")) { 
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Reset to Awaiting Approval", "Reset", new { itemChangeID = change.ItemChangeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Reset this change to Awaiting Approval?", OnSuccess = "actionCompleted" })
        } else {
                @changeStatus.ToDisplayString()
        }

        @break;
 }

  </td> 
  <td  id="tdreasonId-@change.ItemChangeID">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.RejectedReason)          </td>
} else {
    <td colspan="3">No Change</td>
}
```

(Hard to code in editor box, this could use some cleanup, but I think you will get the idea)

You add this display template (with the file name ItemChangeModel.cshtml) to the Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates folder and it will get used whenever a DisplayFor call is made on that type.

Its been noted in comments that you can't use a method in DisplayFor, but you can change that to an indexed property:

```
public class ChangeLog
{
    public ItemChangeModel this[string key] { get { return Item("Color"); } }
}
```

Then use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChangeLog["Color"])
```

Comment: If you want to get even fancier you can add a DisplayTemplate called ChangeHistory which could iterate the properties and do this as well in a more automated fashion using `ModelMetadata.Properties`.

Comment: I think your answer would work. The comment suggestion would be difficult as there are some differences in each of the properties, but there are enough similarities in the section I'm interested in.  Could you add a little code to your answer. The type returned from ChangeLog.Item is of type ItemChangeModel

Comment: `m => m.ChangeLog.Item("Color")` is not a valid expression that a strongly typed DisplayFor helper would accept. It contains a function call and this is not supported.

Comment: Are you sure, in MVC3 it handles calls and more complex member access, specifically single param member index access... would have to put together a little sample to try, guess I can do that.

Comment: Dmitri is correct you cannot use a method to invoke DisplayFor, but you can just as easily use `@Html.Display` or you can change the `Item` property to be an indexed property as opposed to a method.

Comment: Edited above to reflect using indexed property